# How can I efficiently draw multiple connections between nodes?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I believe the following figure has been drawn very inefficiently. I need help drawing the same figure using nodes and relative positioning (right=of, below=of, ...etc) instead of using the absolute positioning.

This is my code:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{article}
\usepackage[latin1]{inputenc}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{amssymb}
\usepackage{times}
\usepackage{tikz}

\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings,arrows,positioning,shapes}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,>=latex',scale=0.8]

\node (d) at (-6,0) [draw,shape=rectangle,minimum width=8ex,minimum 
height=5ex,align=center]{Data\\source};

\draw (-4.5,2.5) rectangle node [align=center]{Partition \\ into blocks \\ and serial\\to parallel\\conversion} (-2,-2.5);

\draw (-1,2.5) rectangle node [align=center]{Division\\into\\subblocks} (1.5,-2.5);

\draw (2.5,1.5) rectangle node {IDFT} ++(1.5,1);
\draw (2.5,0) rectangle node {IDFT} ++(1.5,1);
\draw (2.5,-2.5) rectangle node {IDFT} ++(1.5,1);
\draw [->](d) -- (-4.5,0);
\draw [->](-2,0) -- node [above]{$D$}(-1,0);

\begin{scope}\fontsize{20}{19} \selectfont
\node at (2,-0.5) {$\vdots$};
\end{scope}

%% X-Circle 1
\begin{scope}
\node at (9.5,2) [above left]{$W_1$};
\draw [->] (6.4,2) -- (9.5,2);
\draw [->] (4,2) -- ++(1.6,0);
\node at (4.5,2) [above]{$b_1$};
\draw [fill] (4.5,2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [->](4.5,2) --  (4.5,-3);
\draw [clip] (6,2) circle (0.4cm);
\draw (5.5,2.5) -- ++(1,-1);
\draw (5.5,1.5) -- ++(1,1);
\end{scope}

%% X-Circle 2

\begin{scope}
\node at (9.5,0.5) [above left]{$W_2$};
\draw [->] (4.0,0.5) -- ++(2.6,0);
\draw [->] (7.4,0.5) -- (9.5,0.5);
\node at (5.0,0.5) [above]{$b_2$};
\draw [fill] (5.0,0.5) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [->](5.0,0.5) -- (5,-3);
\draw [clip] (7,0.5) circle (0.4cm);
\draw (6.5,1) -- ++(1,-1);
\draw (6.5,0) -- ++(1,1);
\end{scope}

%% X-Circle 3
\begin{scope}
\node at (9.5,-2) [above left]{$W_{\! M}$};
\draw [->] (4,-2) -- ++(3.6,0);
\draw [->] (8.4,-2) -- (9.5,-2);
\node at (5.5,-2) [above]{$b_M$};
\draw [fill] (5.5,-2) circle (1.5pt);
\draw [->](5.5,-2) -- (5.5,-3);
\draw [clip] (8,-2) circle (0.4cm);
\draw (7.5,-1.5) -- ++(1,-1);
\draw (7.5,-2.5) -- ++(1,1);
\end{scope}

\draw (4,-3)rectangle node{Optimization for $W$} ++(4.5,-1);
\draw [->](6,-3) -- ++(0,4.6);
\draw [->](7,-3) -- ++(0,3.1);
\draw [->](8,-3) -- ++(0,0.6);
\draw (9.5,2.5)rectangle node{$+$} ++(1,-5);
\draw [->](10.5,0)-- node [above]{$S$}(11.2,0);

\begin{scope}\fontsize{20}{19} \selectfont
\node at (7.7,-0.5) {$\vdots$};
\end{scope}

\draw [->](1.5,2) -- ++(1,0);
\draw [->](1.5,0.5) -- ++(1,0);
\draw [->](1.5,-2.0) -- ++(1,0);

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is an almost complete rewrite. Since most of the stuff is repeated three times, you can take advantage of a foreach loop that each time draws one set of repated parts.

I got bored and skipped the remaining parts but I think you can take it from there

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,arrows,positioning}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=1pt,>=latex',
               tall/.style={align=center,text width=2cm,minimum height=5cm},
               crossed/.style={circle,draw,minimum height=8mm,outer sep=0,path picture={\draw
               (path picture bounding box.south east) -- (path picture bounding box.north west)
               (path picture bounding box.south west) -- (path picture bounding box.north east);
                   }}]

\node (d) at (-6,0) [draw,align=center]{Data\\ source};
\node[draw,tall,right= of d] (e) {Partition into blocks and serial to parallel conversion} ;
\node[draw,tall,right= of e] (f) {Division into subblocks};
\node[draw,inner xsep=5mm] (op) at (6.25,-4) {Optimization for $W$};
\draw[->] (d) -- (e) -- (f);

\foreach \x[count=\xi] in {0.1,0.4,0.9}{
\draw node[draw,inner ysep=5pt]
    (idft-\xi) at ([xshift=2cm]$(f.north east)!\x!(f.south east)$) {IDFT}
    node[circle,inner sep=2pt,outer sep=0,fill,right=3mm + 5*\xi mm of idft-\xi,
         label={$\ifnum\xi=3b_M\else b_\xi\fi$}] (b-\xi){}
    node[crossed,right=1cm+\xi cm of idft-\xi] (c-\xi){};
\draw[->] (f.east|-idft-\xi) -- (idft-\xi);
\draw[->] (b-\xi) -- (b-\xi|-op.north);
\draw[<-] (c-\xi) -- (c-\xi|-op.north);
\draw[->] (idft-\xi) --(c-\xi);
}

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot percusse, your solution helped me so much. One thing is still unclear to me which is how can I make the "_(op)_" node positioned relatively as the other nodes? The problem is when I try to scale the figure or change "_node distance_" I find this node dislocated. I appreciate your help.

Comment: @AboAmmar You can place it relative to d,e, or f nodes to your liking with for example `below right=3cm and -1cm of d` etc.